# Why did Akash (sky) betray the gods?

Tags: krishna

After the marriage of Devaki, there was an *Akashvani* (voice of sky) warning Kamsa (Devaki's Brother) that her eight son would kill him. When Kamsa tried to kill Devaki, Devaki's husband stopped Kamsa assuring him that he will give Kamsa all eight sons.

The question is: If birth of Krishna was a preplanned agenda and Krishna was going to kill Kamsa, what was the point of warning Kamsa?

P.S. If I misinterpreted *Akashvani* as *Voice of Sky*, please correct me. If it meant Prophecy, then whose voice was it? And, why did he/she/it reveals the plan to Kamsa?

Comment: @learningbrain I think the name was Kans, not Kamsa..

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamsa

Comment: One of the positive that I can think of  Because of the warning or prophecy made to Kamsa, Kamsa was constantly thinking of Sri Krishna 24X7 (out of fear and anger), This became His sadhana and eventually He got Moksha because the Lord liberates the one who constatnly thinks of Him, although it is out of anger and fear. All the best

Comment: So that kamsa can increase his atrocities more and more and it will enable krishnas coming more faster.
Another reason was so that while residing in braja he could enjoy killing and playing with demons which would be sent by kamsa in near future.

Comment: During his birth Krishna will escape death from Kamsa, and after Krishna escaped from Kamsa, Kamsa sent somany rakshasa's in search of Krishna. Krishna wantedly waited and killed every rakshasa that Kamsa had sent. It is Krishna's plan to reduce number of rakshasas on earth.